# Is it possible to have a Type Parameter that extends 2 other type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

Here is my goal: I want to have an argument that needs to be two separate types at the same time.

The goal here is to extract two different types from a single object using just generics (no casting or `instanceof`).

My idea is to have a third type parameter that `extends` the other two.

```
class DualType<A, B> {
    A a;
    B b;
    <T extends A & B> DualType(T obj) {
         a = obj;
         b = obj;
    }
}
```

This does not work. Since java does not support multiple inheritance, and there isn't a way the compiler can guarantee that B isn't another class, we get an error.

My question is this: Is there some way to define a type parameter that constrains it to only be used with interfaces? I would assume you would be able to use `implements` rather than `extends` but as we all know, only `super` and `extends` are valid in type parameter declarations. Is there a workaround for this? Or is it simply not possible?

The thing I am trying to achieve here isn't for some practical purpose, but I rather would just like to know if something like this is possible at all in Java?

Comment: from Java Language Specification [4.4. Type Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeBound): `TypeBound:  ...  extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}` and `AdditionalBound: & InterfaceType`

Comment: @user16320675 This is fascinating: **It is a compile-time error if any of the types I1, ..., In is a class type or type variable**. This is the error I am seeing. I suppose you can only have at most one type variable after "extends".

Comment: That is the part I skipped in(indicated by the `...`): `TypeBound:
extends TypeVariable` (no additional bound) - yes. only one type variable!  :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to define a type parameter that constrains it to only be used with interfaces?

Compiler can't know whether `A` and `B` are interfaces or classes, since these type variables are only placeholders and actual types will be provided at runtime.

And since type variable `T` has multiple bounds `<T extends A & B>` only `A` can be a class and `B` should be an interface. But `B` can be pretty much anything, and therefore your constructor causes a compilation error.

> only "super" and "extends" are valid in type parameter declarations

That's not correct. We can use `super` only with wild cards, not with bounded types. `T super MyInterface` will not compile. With bounded type parameters we can use only `extends`.

And it's not possible to let the compiler know that `B` is an interface by using `extends`. Even if bound would be an interface `B extends MyInterface` it doesn't imply that `B` expected to be an interface.

There's no way to achieve what you're trying to do.